# Use visual character-wise selection as auto-fill for Vim substitute command

Tags: vim

Imagine that [ ] represents a selection. So given

```
This is pi with the 10th through 20th digits obscured: 3.14159265[3589793238]46264338327950288419716939937510...
```

the visual selection would be `3589793238`.

In Sublime Text, when you have some text selected, and then press Ctrl+h to start the search/replace feature, it will auto-fill the search box with the currently selected text. Is there a way to emulate this in Vim? That is, assuming I am in character-wise visual mode and have made the selection indicated above, I would then press some shortcut combo and Vim would yield `:%s/3589793238/` in the command line. That way I could simply complete it like so `:%s/3589793238/___/` to replace `3589793238` with `___` throughout the currently open file (without having to manually type `3589793238` into the Vim command-line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In command mode, you can input the content of any register with `<C-R>` followed by its name. So you could yank the currently selected text (yanked text is stored in register `0`) and then input it with `<C-R>0` when writing your substitute command.

To fully automate this, you could add a mapping like so:

```
xmap <leader>s y:%s/<C-R>0/
```